# Single user view in Django API (Rest Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created an `API` on `Django` using the `rest framework`, I populate that through the default `Django Admin Page`.

I've some fields in my `API`, here my `serializers.py`:

```
class HCSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HomeController
        fields = ('full_name','Staff','CID', 'OI', 'Rating', 'GND', 'TWR', 'APP', 'CTR', 'Notes')


class VCSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VisitingController
        fields = ('full_name','CID', 'OI', 'Rating', 'GND', 'TWR', 'APP', 'CTR', 'Notes')
```

my `views.py`:

```
class HCViewSet(APIView):
    def get(self):
        HC = HomeController.objects.all().order_by('full_name')
        serializer = HCSerializer(HC, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class VCViewSet(APIView):
    def get(self):
        VC = VisitingController.objects.all().order_by('full_name')
        serializer = VCSerializer(VC, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

my `models.py`:

```
class HomeController(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    ATM = 'ATM'
    DATM = 'DATM'
    TA = 'TA'
    EC = 'EC'
    FE = 'FE'
    WM = 'WM'
    INS = 'INS'
    MTR = 'MTR'
    BLK = 'BLK'
    Staff = [
        (ATM, 'Air Traffic Manager'),
        (DATM, 'Deputy Air Traffic Manager'),
        (TA, 'Training Administrator'),
        (EC, 'Events Coordinator'),
        (FE, 'Facility Engeneer'),
        (WM, 'Webmaster'),
        (INS, 'Instructor'),
        (MTR, 'Mentor'),
        (BLK, 'Blank'),
    ]
    Staff = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=Staff,
        default=BLK
    )

    CID = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    OI = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='XX')
    Rating = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    NOT_CERTIFIED = 'NC'
    IN_TRAINING = 'IT'
    SOLO_VALIDATION = 'SV'
    CERTIFIED = 'CE'
    Certs = [
        (NOT_CERTIFIED, 'Not certified'),
        (IN_TRAINING, 'In Training'),
        (SOLO_VALIDATION, 'Solo Validation'),
        (CERTIFIED, 'Certified'),
    ]

    GND = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Certs,
        default=NOT_CERTIFIED,
    )
    TWR = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Certs,
        default=NOT_CERTIFIED,
    )
    APP = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Certs,
        default=NOT_CERTIFIED,
    )
    CTR = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Certs,
        default=NOT_CERTIFIED,
    )
    
    Notes = models.CharField(max_length=360, blank=True)

class VisitingController(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    CID = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    OI = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='XX')
    Rating = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    NOT_CERTIFIED = 'NC'
    IN_TRAINING = 'IT'
    SOLO_VALIDATION = 'SV'
    CERTIFIED = 'CE'
    GND_Certs = [
        (NOT_CERTIFIED, 'Not certified'),
        (IN_TRAINING, 'In Training'),
        (SOLO_VALIDATION, 'Solo Validation'),
        (CERTIFIED, 'Certified'),
    ]
    GND = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=GND_Certs,
        default=NOT_CERTIFIED,
    )

    TWR_Certs = [
        (NOT_CERTIFIED, 'Not certified'),
        (IN_TRAINING, 'In Training'),
        (SOLO_VALIDATION, 'Solo Validation'),
        (CERTIFIED, 'Certified'),
    ]
    TWR = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=GND_Certs,
        default=NOT_CERTIFIED,
    )
    APP_Certs = [
        (NOT_CERTIFIED, 'Not certified'),
        (IN_TRAINING, 'In Training'),
        (SOLO_VALIDATION, 'Solo Validation'),
        (CERTIFIED, 'Certified'),
    ]
    APP = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=GND_Certs,
        default=NOT_CERTIFIED,
    )
    CTR_Certs = [
        (NOT_CERTIFIED, 'Not certified'),
        (IN_TRAINING, 'In Training'),
        (SOLO_VALIDATION, 'Solo Validation'),
        (CERTIFIED, 'Certified'),
    ]
    CTR = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=GND_Certs,
        default=NOT_CERTIFIED,
    )
    Notes = models.CharField(max_length=360, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

My question: the `API` works fine and I'm able to get all the results, but I'm looking to create an `endopoint` like `/api/<int:CID>` that returns just one user. I would like to use the field '`CID`' to filter. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: which one of these two models is the one you need to output? you said you need to output `user` but there is no such `User` model

Comment: I need to output the HomeController and the VisitingController model. Like I make an API call to /api/153 and it returns the model that has the CID 153.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you need to create the detail views.

```
from django.http import Http404

class HCDetailViewSet(APIView):
    def get_object(self, CID):
        try:
            return HomeController.objects.get(CID=CID)
        except HomeController.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, CID, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(CID)
        serializer = HCSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class VCDetailViewSet(APIView):
    def get_object(self, CID):
        try:
            return VisitingController.objects.get(CID=CID)
        except VisitingController.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, CID, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(CID)
        serializer = VCSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And in urls.py, you have to add the URLs for the detail views.

```
path('hc/<str:CID>', HCDetailViewSet.as_view(), name="hc_detail_view")
path('vc/<str:CID>', VCDetailViewSet.as_view(), name="vc_detail_view")
```